# virtual printer GATT server android device phisical

Tags: android, bluetooth, virtual

The GATT server only simulates a BLE device for another cell phone, in this case I need two devices with Bluetooth to work. However, I would like to do everything on the same device.

I need to simulate a bluetoothLE virtual device on Android, the android must connect to it and exchange information, and what is sent to the ble device must be saved in a file inside the android, everything must happen inside a real Android device simulating a bluetoothLE virtual device.

I have apk's that only send prints via a bluetoothLE device, however we will no longer use printers, in the app there is no option to save as a PDF or send it to the Android printer.

I don't have access to the application source to make changes directly to the source code.

Faced with the problem, my idea would be to create a virtual BLE device where the android could virtually connect to it and send the data that would be saved in a file. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a BLE server and connect to it within the same device. The "loopback" interface which typically exists for IP has nothing similar when it comes to BLE.

Physically it's typically not even possible for the radio to communicate with itself. The hardware is at any given time point either in TX or RX mode only and uses a scheduler to make it appear as it can perform multiple operations concurrently.